# Is there no closing tag matchig in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor

I am a web developer and need closing tag matching for HTML. I always use Netbeans but a giving Eclipse a try for the first time. By default it seems to have closing brace matching for PHP/javascript, etc. But I don't see the closing tag matching when I clock on an opening tag. Is there some way to turn this feature on or does it not exist?

Also how does one change syntax colors in Eclipse, I don't see those options in Windows >> Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this effect?

[image]

It should be enable by default .

To change the color syntax ,  go to `Window --> Preferences` and  type `color` in the top left search box  .Then all the setting about color will be filtered out.

You can change the color of the matching tags in the `General ---> Editor ---> Text Editors ----> Annotation`.

[image]

You can also try this [Eclipse Color Theme plugin](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) which has already includes many popular color themes.

P.S All the settings are based on the eclipse 3.7 Indigo Version.

Comment: I don't the option of changing the matching tags. Why do you think this could be? I have 3.7.2